# re-Printing Chronometer value gives Integer value instead of String

Tags: android, kotlin, chronometer

I am trying to pull a String value equal to the moment the chronometer stops as in "01:21" but the elapsed time gives an integer value, as in "11322".

```
val chronometer = findViewById<Chronometer>(R.id.chronometer)
chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
chronometer.format = "%s"
chronometer.start()
button.setOnClickListener {
    val elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.base
    header.text = elapsedtime.toString()
    Toast.makeText(this,"$elapsedTime",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be precise you get a long value and not an integer because both `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` and `chronometer.base` return a long value.

I have to disappoint you, currently there is no way to directly get the shown time of a chronometer, but of course you can convert the milliseconds you got to minutes and seconds, so you can show it again.

---

Here's my example of how it could work:

```
private fun calculateTime(chronometerMillis : Long) {
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(chronometerMillis)
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(chronometerMillis) - (minutes * 60)

    println("Recreated time: $minutes:$seconds")
}
```

If you now call this method with the value `81000`, which is 1 Minute and 21 Seconds (just like your chronometer), it prints `Recreated time: 1:21`.

---

To use it in your project just return a String:

```
private fun calculateTime(chronometerMillis : Long) : String {
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(chronometerMillis)
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(chronometerMillis) - (minutes * 60)

    return "$minutes:$seconds"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private  fun formattedChronometer(chronometer: Chronometer): String {
    val elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.base
    val time = elapsedTime / 1000
    val minutes = time / 60
    val seconds = time % 60
    return String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds)
}
```

Managed to solve it using this function after looking into the documentation

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty equal to my solution, but without TimeUnit methods.